# NodeJs error: Cannot GET /admin when using router

Tags: node.js, express, router

I am trying to make a route for admin page.

Here is what I got so far:

**app.js**

```
app.engine('.hbs', expressHsb({defaultLayout: 'default', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));


const adminRoutes = require('./routes/adminRoutes');

app.get('/admin', adminRoutes);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

**adminRoutes.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const adminController = require('../controllers/adminController');


router.all('/*', (req, res, next) => {

    req.app.locals.layout = 'admin';

    next();
});


router.route('/')
    .get(adminController.index);

module.exports = router;
```

**adminController.js**

```
module.exports = {
    index: (req, res) => {
        res.render('admin/index', {layout: false});
    }
};
```

I am not sure what am I missing here. I have defined route in my `app.js`
but I am still getting `Cannot GET /admin`.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do

`app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);`

Instead of

`app.get('/admin', adminRoutes);`

in app.js

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that! Now is working thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

### app.js

change `GET` to `use` and restart your server.

```js
    const adminRoutes = require('./routes/adminRoutes');

    // change get to use it
    app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
```

To know more Route:
https://github.com/sagormax/node-admin/blob/master/routes/index.js

To know more app.js : https://github.com/sagormax/node-admin/blob/master/app.js